# Post hoc test in Generalised linear mixed models: how to do?

Tags: r, count, nested, mixed-models

I am working with a mixed model (glmmadmb) in R for count data. I have one random factor (Locality), and one fixed factor(Habitat). The fixed factor has two levels, and the random factor has seven levels. I want to do comparisons between the two levels of fixed factor within each of the seven levels of random factor. But I don't know how to do it in R. I am very new to R. Can anyone help me? Many thanks.

This is my glmm formula for over dispersed data:

```
    model<-glmmadmb(Species.abundance~Habitat(1|Locality:Habitat),
                    data=data,family='nbinom1')
```

I tried it with just "Habitat" but it is clearly not taking Locality into account:

```
    summary(glht(model,linfct=mcp(Habitat='Tukey')))

 Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: glmmadmb(formula = Species.abundance ~ Habitat + (1 | Locality:Habitat), 
    data = data, family = "nbinom1")

Linear Hypotheses:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
Fynbos - Forest == 0  -0.2614     0.2010  -1.301    0.193
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably just do separate tests within each Locality, and do multiple-comparison corrections if you like. Functions from `plyr` are convenient, but not necessary, to do this, something like

```
library(plyr)
library(glmmADMB)
model.list <- dlply(data,"Locality",glmmadmb,
                    formula=Species.abundance~Habitat,
                    family="nbinom1")
p.vals <- laply(model.list,function(x) coef(summary(x))[2,"Pr(>|z|)"])
p.adjust(pvals)
```

(I can't guarantee that this actually works since you haven't given a reproducible example and I can't be bothered to invent one ...)

Comment: `laply` is a plyr function. Takes a list as first argument and returns an array (or matrix).